# how to overlay child form in parent using c#?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a question about child form , lets give an example , I have parent form then I have 2 child forms. When I open first child form in parent it's okay but if i open the second one it will overlay on the first one. How can I close child form 1 when I open child form 2.

this is my code for opened child form

```
Form2 obj = new Form2(); obj.MdiParent = this; obj.Show();

Form3 obj = new Form3(); obj.MdiParent = this; obj.Show();
```

regards Dlovan

Comment: The Forms obviously have different names, but all you need to do is call [`obj.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on whatever Form you want to close before you call `obj.Show()` on the new form.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but how to check if child form is opened to close it ?

Comment: You can either keep track of them, or use [MdiChildren](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are calling other forms from a form which is set as IsMdiContainer = true;

add this code before you call another form to show up

```
foreach (object formObj in MdiChildren) ((Form)formObj).Close();
```

like this

```
foreach (object formObj in MdiChildren) ((Form)formObj).Close();
Form2 obj = new Form2(); obj.MdiParent = this; obj.Show();
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly , but it changes form position how to make static and not change when opened again ?

Comment: to remain in the position top left corner you have to code like

Comment: Form2 obj = new Form2() { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual, Location = new Point(0, 0)}; obj.MdiParent = this; obj.Show();